# How to detect SQL errors in c++ code at compile time

Tags: c++, sql, jenkins

So, I want SQL errors to prevent C++ code from building successfully.

What I was thinking was compiling via some cmake script or something that would grep the cpp files for SQL and validate the SQL.

I know I could add some kind of runtime error checking but I don't want the following code to build sucessfully (not a question about pqxx, but SQL errors in C++ in general):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>

using namespace std;
using namespace pqxx;

int main() {
    connection conn("dbname=d user=u");

    conn.prepare("invalid_sql", "SELECT 1 FROM WHERE a = $1");

    nontransaction txn(conn);

    txn.prepared("invalid_sql")(1.0).exec();

    cout << "the process already died due to invalid SQL" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't. To do so, you would need a complete parser for SQL, a complete parser for C++ to extract the relevant strings only to specific classes, functions, or other, verify it, and then wrap it in a CMake script during configuration. Don't do this. Just write valid code.

Comment: yeah, that's what I want.  I write valid code, but I have to execute the binary to find a runtime error and then go back and recompile.  Basically I want this to fail in jenkins

Comment: and basically, I would only have to write that parser once and never have to bother with that again. also, it would prevent someone else from checking in invalid SQL

Comment: in ancient times db vendors have C preprocessors for mixed C/SQL sources. This part of market is dead, probably nobody wite such systems in C

Comment: Really. I'm still using SQL.  I'm interested to know if there's a better alternative.  It's the most important technology and marketable skill that exists in my opinion.

Comment: other than fortran that is

Comment: Replacing your existing questions with completely different questions that invalidate the comments and answer is *not an improvement*.  That's not what the SO message is telling you to do.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317446/when-to-ask-a-new-question-or-edit-an-old-question.  If you can't post new questions right now, that's what you get for posting stuff that gets downvoted recently.

Comment: Which post are you talking about?  I don't see any comments from Eugene on this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this question.  The other answer is fine, but that's not what I did.

What I decided to do was put the prepared statements in a init_sql() method and call that using boost/test/unit_test.hpp against a replicated database with jenkins, which provides notifications for unit test failures.

Answer (score 0):

You can, sort-of...

One approach is [Boost meta_parsing](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/metaparse/getting_started_with_boost_metap.html), another is using [C++11's user-defined literal types](https://github.com/rep-movsd/see-phit). I couldn't find a worked example for SQL, but perhaps as C++11 matures someone will come up with one.

Comment: Thanks, I sure will look at that when I have time, but I'm thinking about just using grep and regex to pull the string and then fork a process that tries to execute the SQL against a dummy replicated database at compile time.  The problem I am thinking of now if the parameter was a stringstream - might need a parser for that

Comment: That would indeed be a far more achievable approach! Also, if you have any parameter replacement code, you cannot of course test that at compile time.

Comment: well, the string can contain $1, $2, $3 for prepared statements.  I'll probably handle that with regex.  I guess the alternative is to use a pre-compiled stored procedure for absolutely everything, I guess that's what most people are doing.  Still it's not enfored by the compiler and I'd still need to have a wrapper script

Comment: so I edited the question to display the prepared statements.  What I'm going to do is put all the prepare statements in a init_sql() method and call that using <boost/test/unit_test.hpp> against a replicated db.  I guess there's no way around it.